# pagination not working during search in Django

Tags: python, django

Pagination is not working while doing a search.

`views.py`:

```
def crud(request):

    user_list = User.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    users = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'crud/crud.html', {'users': users})


def search(request):

    users = None
    fname = request.POST.get('search')
    try:
        user_list = User.objects.filter(first_name__startswith=fname) | 
        User.objects.filter(last_name__startswith=fname)
        paginator = Paginator(user_list, 3)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        users = paginator.get_page(page)
    except:
        pass
    return render(request, 'crud/crud.html', {'users': users}, {'fname': fname})
```

`Crud.html`:

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="{% url 'search' %}">

{% csrf_token %}

         <input type="text" name="search" value="{{ fname }}" 

         placeholder="Search  name"/>

</form>
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: use 4 spaces in front of your code.  Please add your question to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a try for a filter in Django.
The result is every time a query.

so this should be work fine and work fine for me:

```
users = None
fname = request.POST.get('search')
user_list = User.objects.filter(first_name__startswith=fname)
paginator = Paginator(user_list, 3)
page = request.GET.get('page')
users = paginator.get_page(page)
return render(request, 'crud/crud.html', {'users': users, 'fname': fname})
```

Comment: My search function is working normally, but with pagination it is not working.

Comment: {% if users.has_previous %}
       <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">previous</a> {% endif %} 
<span class="current">
      Page {{ users.number }} of {{ users.paginator.num_pages }}.
  </span>
   {% if users.has_next %}
       <a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">next</a>
       <a href="?page={{ users.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
   {% endif %}

Comment: My search function is working normally, but with pagination it is not working. below html code is for pagination. While I am clicking on next it is not working during search.

Comment: @AakashVaghela what do you mean with 'not working'. Please explain what you get and what you expect and what you have tried.

Comment: My pagination is not working with search. I have two views as mentioned in code. Without search my pagination(3 records per page) is working. With search If I am getting records(4 records means in 2 pages), then while clicking on next button I am getting all the records, not only one record in second page.      As While clicking on next my GET method is getting called which is in crud.

Comment: Page is getting refreshed. So my first name value is also getting refreshed. So in the next page it is getting None in search function. and getting message as "Cannot use None as a query value"

Comment: I am facing same problem, Anyone here to understand and help? @AakashVaghela Did you find any solution?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new question with your code? I don't know if we will finde a solution in the comment section.

Comment: You can find a sample working code at the following link for pagination with search:  https://gist.github.com/LowerDeez/b39f682c786698790e5af81e30263a03